Databricks connection pool(ing) using python
I have a python application which I need to connect with databricks (Databricks SQL Connector). The process for that is quite simple -

connect with dbr
execute your query
get the result
close the connection

Example from - https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html#manage-cursors-and-connections
from databricks import sql
import os

connection = sql.connect(server_hostname = os.getenv("DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME"),
                         http_path       = os.getenv("DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH"),
                         access_token    = os.getenv("DATABRICKS_TOKEN"))

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from range(10)")
print(cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
connection.close()


But the issue here is that connecting to dbr takes almost 15-16 seconds in best case scenarios which is too much for an API I am building.
So to overcome, I implemented a custom "connection pooling" technique -
from app.utils.constants import DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME, DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH, DATABRICKS_TOKEN
import threading
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class ConnectionPool:
    def __init__(self, max_size=5):
        self.pool = []
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def create_connection(self):
        logging.info("Creating a new connection")
        return sql.connect(server_hostname=DATABRICKS_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
                           http_path=DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH,
                           access_token=DATABRICKS_TOKEN)

    def get_connection(self):
        with self.lock:
            if self.pool:
                logging.info(f"Reusing connection from pool. Pool size before: {len(self.pool)}")
                return self.pool.pop()
            else:
                logging.info("No available connections in pool, creating a new one")
                return self.create_connection()

    def release_connection(self, connection):
        with self.lock:
            if len(self.pool) < self.max_size:
                self.pool.append(connection)
                logging.info(f"Connection released back to pool. Pool size now: {len(self.pool)}")
            else:
                connection.close()
                logging.info("Pool is full. Closing the connection")

connection_pool = ConnectionPool(max_size=5)

I know there are various factors which I have to factor as part of "best practices" like Manage Connection Lifetimes (Connection Timeout, Max Connection Lifetime), Connection Validation and Retry Logic - which I believe can be a topic of future discussions.
Now my main point currently is, the technique I have used is good enough for a basic production PoC or connection pooling can deteriorate performance (and be a mistake in long-run) or is there any out-of-the box solution for something like this (for ex - in rails active-record also has similar concept but built-in)?
Any thoughts/suggestions/reviews are welcome :)
